# Hum from Opel Corsa GplTech when throttling

Tags: fuel-system, noise, opel, corsa, lpg

I've got a 2010 Opel corsa d 1.2 GplTech, now with about 84000 km.
The car seems fine, does not consume excessively and even the mechanic said this January that it feels solid.

However, when I'm on LPG and go on partial throttle I hear a low-pitch 'humming' kind of a low note, must be few hundred Hz. This does not happen if I'm running on gas (well, technically the gas is the other, anyway the regular one) so I believe it should be somewhere in the LPG circuit.

Any clue about the possible cause?

Comment: Mine (2019 Corsa E) does the same, it looks like Landi's injectors are causing the hum. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: @DDS you may be interested in my - late - answer, as you may have to replace the expansion chamber

Answer (score 2):

I got the car to a shop, and they found the cause for the humming. I guess it can be useful to others with the same issue.

What happened, was that the LPG expansion chamber (this particular model, at least) has an approximate lifetime of 100'000 km and, while it works quite well during that span, it gets clogged with residuals from the gas. Once (well, a bit before) that happens, you've got to replace the expansion chamber because it doesn't work properly anymore.

In my case, the residuals also got into the downstream filter and (LPG) intake valves, so the shop replaced all of them. Now the hum is gone, I even put some 70'000 more kms in it. Guess it's almost time for another replacement.